How do I send a notification to another device in a React Native application?
I want to send a notification to another device using the React Native app itself.
Previously, I was using the Firebase Rest API. However, it is no longer working. The Firebase cloud messaging API has changed.It requests an access token, which requires me to login or provide access. However, this is not required in the application. When a user posts a story in the app, a post notification is generated. How do I go about implementing this?

So to understand better, do you want to send a notification without a service between the devices?

@AlexMamo I want to send a notification using react native code.Because I'm using Strapi. So the backend is handled on the react native side. So that after insertion,  notification will be fired

There is no (and never has been a) way to securely send a message directly from one device to another with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Calling the REST API directly from your client-side code always puts your users at risk, which is why this has been made a lot harder in the v1 API that was introduced in 2017 and is now mandatory. --- Sending a message to a device with FCM must be done from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or something like Cloud Run/Cloud Functions.

If you don't want to use any notification tools - then check the approcahes Polling or WebSockets.
Polling is a simple approach, where the client checks the backend periodically for new stories. This is easier to implement but may have some delay based on the polling interval. (easy but with some delay)
WebSockets provide real-time notifications and are more efficient for real-time updates. However, this approach requires more setup on both the server and client sides. (real-time with more setup)
